# jquery: dynamically bind events to form elements

Tags: jquery, search, constructor

I am trying to build a jquery based advance search query constructor. The live version of the design built using the MooTools framework is here http://opl.bibliocommons.com/search

Now to the problem, I have a div with the controls that has to be dynamically created on click of "Add more" button. Once the new div is created, I need to bind events to controls inside the div.

The Mootools version of the code is as below:

```
add_query_part: function(ev) {
    if(ev) ev.stop();
    this.query_chunks[0].addClass('removable');
    var query_chunk = this.query_chunks[0].clone().set({'class': 'query_chunk query_piece','id':"query_chunk_"+(++this.term_count)}).inject($('query_parts'));
    var search_param_select = query_chunk.getElement('select').set({
      'class': 'parameter',
      'id':'parameter_'+this.term_count,
      'style': 'margin-right:3px'
    });
    var keyword = query_chunk.getElement('input[type=text]').set({
      'class': 'operand text',
      'id':'keyword_'+(this.term_count),
      'style':'margin-right:3px',
      'value': ''
    });
    var remove_btn = query_chunk.getElement('a').set({
      'class': 'remove_btn',
      'id':'remove_'+(this.term_count)
    });
    $("query_chunk_"+this.term_count).addClass('removable');

    this.query_chunks.push(query_chunk);
    remove_btn.addEvent('click', this.remove_query_part.bindWithEvent(this));
    keyword.addEvent('keyup', this.construct_query.bindWithEvent(this));
    keyword.addEvent('mouseup', this.construct_query.bindWithEvent(this));
    search_param_select.addEvent('change', this.construct_query.bindWithEvent(this));
    return query_chunk;
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) will help you do what you want!